# AWS api gateway proxy to Application load balancer for multipart/form-data not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I have my microservice running in AWS ecs fargate. one of api is to upload file. (xls) file. I have api gateway deployed for any request to passthrough to ALB and ALB to ECS targets.

When i upload file using postman and API gateway base URL, data is altered when it reaches to fargate. EXcel read is not working due to incorrect data. 
But When I tried directly using ALB URL, file upload and excel read success.

Issue appears only for multi part data,Other API works fine. Even Image is also blank when tried using multi part.

So I figured out that some issue/settings to be done in API gateway.
In API gateway I have:
/{Proxy}/ANY and HTTP link passthrough ALB URL.
I have also tried adding multipart/form-data in binary settings of API gateway. still issue in reading file. Data is not same and altered.
Any suggestion to fix this?